# Преобразование двухтабличного запроса MySQL в ассоциативный массив PHP

Tags: mysql, массивы, pdo

Здравсвуйте!

Ситуация: есть база данных теста в MySQL с таблицами:
 - вопрос(столбцы - ID, QUESTION),
 - ответ(столбцы - ID, ANSWER, QUESTION_ID),
 - результат(столбцы - ID, USER, RESULT).

К каждому вопросу есть 4 варианта ответа(маркированы по QUESTION_ID).

Собственно - как создать запрос к базе данных, что-бы в результате получать асоциативный массив вида: **вопрос->варианты ответа**.

Пока смог наваять код который выводит количество вопросов аналогичное количеству вариантов ответов. Ниже представлен код. В нем закоментирован изначальный рабочий асоциативный масив. Хотелось бы такой же получить посредством PDO и MYSQL запроса. Заранее большое спасибо за помощь!

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=matrix', 'root', '');
$sql = 'SELECT `question`, `answer` FROM `questions` INNER JOIN  `answers` WHERE questions.id = answers.question_id;';
$res = $db->query($sql);
$test = $res->FETCHALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//        $test = [
//            'Who are you?' => ["Men", "Women", "Choosen_one", "Mutant"],
//            'What is you name?' => ["Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Tank"],
//            'How old are you?' => ['10', '25', '40', '60'],
//            'Follow the white rabbit?' => ['Yes', 'No', 'Dont_know', 'Maybe'],
//            'What is you favorite food?' => ['Sweets', 'Cakes', 'Meat', 'Vegetables']
//        ];

$questions = array_keys($test);
shuffle($questions);
foreach ($questions as $value) {
    $answers = $test[$value];
    shuffle($answers);
    echo "<b>{$value}</b><br/>";
    foreach ($answers as $value2) {
        echo "<input type='radio' name='$value' value=$value2 required>";
        echo "{$value2}<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: `SELECT question, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT answer ORDER BY answer ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS answers
FROM questions
LEFT JOIN answer ON questions.id = answers.question_id
GROUP BY question.id;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PDO умеет строить массив с указанной вами структурой. Надо только указать это ключами [PDO::fetchall](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchall.php). Сам SQL запрос модифицировать не нужно:

```
$sql = 'SELECT `question`, `answer` FROM `questions` INNER JOIN  `answers` WHERE questions.id = answers.question_id;';
$res = $db->query($sql);
$test = $res->FETCHALL(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
print_r($test);
```

В таком режиме fetchall сгруппирует значения как раз по первому столбцу выборки. Если надо группировать по какому нибудь другому столбцу, то его номер (начиная с 0) надо передать вторым параметром.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете воспользоваться следующим запросом

```
SELECT
  questions.question AS question,
  GROUP_CONCAT(answers.answer) AS answer
FROM
  questions
LEFT JOIN
  answers
WHERE
  questions.id = answers.question_id
GROUP BY
  questiron.id
```

GROUP_CONCAT() вернет строку, в которой ответы будут разделены запятой, преобразовать эту в строку можно при помощи функции explode().

```
$test = [];
while($question = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) {
  $test[$question['question']] = explode(',', $question['answer']);
}
```