# json_decode возвращает пустой результат

Tags: php, json

mysqli

```
SELECT ... ,concat('[[', GROUP_CONCAT(`id`, ',', '\"',`name`, '\"'  SEPARATOR '],['),']]') as npc
```

С базы прилетает строка такого вида (json):

```
var_dump($row['npc']);//→ string(62) "[[679,"<Привратник> Хранитель Храма"]]"
```

Хочу преобразовать данную строку в массив, но не удается

```
$row['npc'] = json_decode($row['npc']);// пусто
```

Если скопировать строку из браузера и подставить в json_decode

```
$row['npc'] = json_decode('[[679,"<Привратник> Хранитель Храма"]]');
```

то преобразовать получается.
Что за ерунда не понимаю :(

Comment: Посмотрите на работу с БД черед PDO. Оно умеет создавать готовые массивы на основе развернутых данных. И никакие group_concat не нужны. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/504422/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-mysql-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-php/504445#504445

Answer (score 6):

Если json_decode вернул пустоту, значит при декодировании произошла ошибка. Которую надо смотреть с помощью [json_last_error](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-last-error.php) и сооответственно исправлять. Скорее всего проблема банально с кодировкой.

Но вообще, конечно, генерить джейсон руками(!) в SQL запросе(!!) - это жесть из жести. Непонятно, почему нельзя получить данные и потом нормально их закодировать

Comment: Можно конечно  из двух implode() распарсить двумерные массив, просто хотелось как проще обойтись  одним json_decode :)

Comment: @ruslan79k так за каким вам в sql формировать json? каким implode()? достали данные в массив и json_encode в помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, на вашем сервере включен magic_quotes_gpc. Либо [отключите](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) его, либо запустите `$stringJSON` через `stripslashes()` перед его использованием.

```
$stringJSON = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ?
    stripslashes($_GET['jsonstring']) : $_GET['jsonstring'];
```