# Объединение двух таблиц

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть таблица с источниками звонков:

```
   id | name
------------------
    1 | Источник 1    
    2 | Источник 2    
    3 | Источник 3
```

И таблица с количеством этих звонков:

```
   id | date     | operator | id_source | sum
 ---------------------------------------------
    1 |2016-08-31| ivan     | 1         | 32
    2 |2016-08-31| ivan     | 2         | 25
    3 |2016-08-31| ivan     | 3         | 10

    4 |2016-08-31| petr     | 1         | 8
    5 |2016-08-31| petr     | 2         | 7
    6 |2016-08-31| petr     | 3         | 19

    7 |2016-08-30| petr     | 1         | 5
    8 |2016-08-30| petr     | 2         | 26
    9 |2016-08-30| petr     | 3         | 45
```

В итоге нужно сделать, чтобы в профиле, например у Петра, была сводная таблица по его принятым звонкам, вида:

```
 Дата      | Источник 1 | Источник 2 | Источник 3 
-------------------------------------------------
2016-08-31 | 8          | 7          | 19    
2016-08-30 | 5          | 26         | 45
```

Количество источников может меняться, поэтому и создана отдельная таблица. Раньше количество источников было одно и тоже, поэтому обходился одной таблицей.

Помогите решить, вторые сутки ломаю голову как это реализовать. Буду благодарен за любую наводку или пример.

Comment: Вот тут есть похожая задача,
Ссылка: http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-table-with-dynamic-columns/

Comment: Думаю что то типа `SELECT date, источник, sum(sum) FROM звонки JOIN источники ON источники.id=звонки.id_source GROUP BY date` это вернет сжатые до дат данные, но по вертикали. А в горизонталь надо разворачивать уже в PHP. Например с помощью группировки в PDO: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/504422/php/504445#504445

Answer (score 3):

Одни из возможных вариантов решения задачи заключается в группировке по дате с использованием функции `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
SELECT
  `date`,
   GROUP_CONCAT(sum ORDER BY id_source) AS calls
FROM
  calls
WHERE
  operator = 'petr'
GROUP BY
  `date`
ORDER BY
  `date` DESC
```

Запрос возвращает два столбца, в первом дата, во втором - через запятую перечислены значения `sum` отсортированные по `source_id`. Для того, чтобы сформировать шапку таблицы достаточно запросить данные из таблицы источников звонков так же отсортировав их по `source_id`.

Comment: Спорно, потому как не получает названия источников. и если в какую то из дат не окажется скажем источника2, то там будет строка только сум 1 и 3 источников и в какие колонки их ставить на клиенте уже понять невозможно.

Comment: @Mike пожалуй да

Comment: спасибо за внимание, нашел ответ, метод называется PIVOT