# Группировка полей sqlite

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, pdo, sqlite3

База данных имеет следующие строки:

```
A, A1, A2, A3
A, A4, A5, A6
A, A7, A8, A9
...
B, B1, B2, B3
B, B4, B5, B6
B, B7, B8, B9
...
```

Мне нужно получить массив на выходе:

[A => [[A1, A2, A3], [A4, A5, A6], ...], B => [[B1, B2, B3], [B4, B5, B6], ...]]

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно это сделать

Comment: Переформулируйте вопрос. База данных не может иметь поля.

Comment: Буквально `select * from table`, далее собрать функцией PDO::fetchall, как тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/504422/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-mysql-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-php/504445#504445

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за ответ. Если Вас не затруднит, не могли бы Вы написать код, у меня пока не получается разобраться. Пересмотрел документацию, не нашёл ничего к сожалению. Решил просто повторить код предложенный по Вашей ссылке, без указания второго параметра работает, но группировка получается не та, по индексу, со вторым параметром - пустоту выдаёт.

Comment: А что там может не получатся, сейчас попробовал на таблице на подобии вашей. `select col1, col2 from table` и fetchall из того ответа выдал точно тот массив какой вам нужен. может вы лишние колонки в select выбираете

Comment: @Mike, а fetchall как используете? Я написал типа $massiv = $rezult -> fetchall(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, 1); - пустота, без единички - выдаёт, пробовал ASSOC на NUM заменить - пустота, без единички тоже самое - работает. Колонки звёздочкой выбираю (то есть все) (PHP7, вдруг в этом дело)

Comment: Я выбирал _точно_ как в том примере, без второго параметра. А колонки выбираю явно указав две, которые из них нужны, та по которой надо группировать  - первая. Иначе фетч конечно ничего не поймет если колонок будет больше или не в том порядке (почему второй параметр не работает - хз).

Comment: @Mike, понятно, тогда придётся перестроить немного вопрос, мне нужно немножко другое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуемся фукнцией выбирающей сразу массив `PDO::fetchAll` и стилями выборки `FETCH_GROUP` который сгруппирует данные по первой колонке и `FETCH_NUM` сделает масссивы строк индексированными только по порядку колонок (исключая имена колонок).

```
$sql = "select X,col1,col2 from TableX";
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

Comment: спасибо Вам за ответы. Всё получилось! Вот что значит браться за дело со свежей головой, извините что сразу не догадался.