# Как создать двумерный массив на основе данных из базы

Tags: php, mysql, динамические-массивы

Здравствуйте. У меня есть двумерный массив:

```
$massiv = array (
 'КАТЕГОРИЯ: Материал' => array (
   0 => 'Дерево',
   1 => 'Сталь',
 ),

 'КАТЕГОРИЯ: Применение' => array (
   0 => 'В сухом помещении',
   1 => 'Сауны',
 ),

);
```

Я же хочу сделать чтобы все эти значения для массива брались из базы данных MySQL, так как параметров может быть неопределенное количество, и вписывать все в код не очень удобно.

То есть, категорий и под категорий может быть сколько угодно.

Категории хранятся в таблице `category` , а подкатегории в таблице `podcat` .

Вот каким образом их привести в подобный массив, я еще не пришел к заключению...

Буду благодарен за любую полезную информацию.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/504422/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-mysql-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-php/504445#504445

Comment: Как они хранятся в базе и как в podcat  указана связь с category?

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan в таблице **podcat** ячейка `id_cat` - в ней числовое значение, соответствует id записи в таблице category

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поменяете запрос под свой если я где то не угадал, но этот код должен вывести то что надо:

```
$sql = 'SELECT `podcat`.`name` as `prodName`, `category`.`name` as `catName` FROM `podcat` INNER JOIN  `category` WHERE podcat.id_cat = category.id;';
$res = $db->query($sql);
$result = [];
while($podcat = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $result[$podcat['catName']][] = $podcat['prodName'];
}

var_dump($result);
```

UPD. Вот вариант без PDO:

```
$sql = 'SELECT `podcat`.`name` as `prodName`, `category`.`name` as `catName` FROM `podcat` INNER JOIN  `category` WHERE podcat.id_cat = category.id;';
$res = mysql_query($query);
$result = [];
while ($podcat = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $result[$podcat['catName']][] = $podcat['prodName'];
}
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: а без PDO не обойтись? у меня mysql

Comment: только получается я получаю КАТЕГОРИЮ, а вместо подкатегорий я получаю ровно столько же категорий, сколько должно быть подкатегорий

Comment: получается вида: КАТЕГОРИЯ (категория, категория, категория) . а нужно КАТЕГОРИЯ (подкатегория, подкатегория, подкатегория)

Comment: Попробуйте сделать `podcat`.`name` as `podName` по аналогии с catName и так же в while заменить, а лучше покажите что получается, потому что должно получаться верно

Comment: Yaroslav Molchan Если вы читали мою ссылку комментарий под вопросом, то могли там увидеть, что PDO может сам делать нужный массив, без использования цикла, что гораздо короче и эффективнее.

Comment: кол-во подкатегорий выводит верное, но вот название берется отактегории

Comment: @Mike но я не использую PDO в своем скрипте

Comment: @Mike а если бы Вы читали комментарии увидели бы что автор вопроса PDO не использует

Comment: @Денис А я рекомендую перейти на PDO, ибо расширение mysql в php более не поддерживается и через пару лет вы вполне можете столкнутся с ситуацией, что на хостинге не будет используемых вами функций (на некоторых хостингах это уже так)

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan , вот результат. на примере использование базы городов: array (size=3)
  'Беларусь' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Беларусь' (length=16)
      1 => string 'Беларусь' (length=16)
      2 => string 'Беларусь' (length=16)
  'Россия' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Россия' (length=12)
  'Италия' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Италия' (length=12)

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan Это особого значения не имеет, вы же на PDO ответ даете :)

Comment: @Денис поправил ответ, попробуйте теперь

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan теперь все отлично. Спасибо за помощь!