# как правильно выбрать и вывести ассоциативный массив из связанных таблиц?

Tags: php, sql, база-данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Связанные таблицы по skills_id, нужно вывести ассоциативный массив в php ,я делаю так :

```
db = Db::getconnection();

  $skillslist = [];

  $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM skills LEFT OUTER JOIN about ON skills.skills_id = about.skills_id');

  $result -> execute();

  while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $skillslist[$row['skill_name']][] =$row;                


  }
  //$row = $result->FETCHALL(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP);

  return $skillslist;
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Преобразование двухтабличного запроса MySQL в ассоциативный массив PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/504422/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-mysql-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-php)

Comment: Для начало структуру ваших таблиц опишите

Comment: @АлексейКузнецов добавил