# Группировка выборки MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Если после выборки из базы у меня есть такой результат...

```
0 : {id: "9", param_id: "1", value: "2"}
1 : {id: "9", param_id: "2", value: "120"}
2 : {id: "9", param_id: "3", value: "7"}
3 : {id: "8", param_id: "1", value: "1"}
4 : {id: "8", param_id: "2", value: "500"}
5 : {id: "8", param_id: "3", value: "6"}
6 : {id: "1", param_id: null, value: null}
7 : {id: "3", param_id: null, value: null}
8 : {id: "4", param_id: null, value: null}
9 : {id: "5", param_id: null, value: null}
```

И мне нужно на фронэнд вывести value по группам param_id (что бы param_id был массивом из элементов value), **мне нужно это делать обработчиком php после выборки или как-то делается это запросом MySql?**

(GROUP BY param_id просто показывает 4 записи а не создает массив из этих данных 10 записей)

Comment: в любом случае это делается на клиенте. но могут помочь готовые функции работы с БД https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/504445/194569

Comment: Спасибо, не знал о таких функциях. Почитаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = []; // Ваш массив с данными выше
$array_new = []; // Новый массив с данными

if ( ! empty($array) && is_array($array)) {
    foreach($array AS $item) {
        $array_new[$item['param_id']][] = $item;
    }
}

print_r($array_new);
```

Comment: отредактировал код