# Как правильно организовать SQL запрос из нескольких таблиц?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

У меня есть таблица `content`, которая имеет вид

`id|name|content|adress`

И таблица `files` которая имеет вид

`id|adress|contentId`

Поле  `contentId` связано с полем `id` таблицы `content`.
Получается, что одной записи в таблице `content` могут соответствовать несколько записей в таблице `files`

Мне нужно вывести c помощью php запись из базы которая будет содержать, поля `name`, `content` и если имеются соответствующие строки в таблице файлов, то адреса этих файлов(их может быть сколько угодно).

Как это правильно сделать? Мне пока на ум кроме как организовать транзакцию с двумя отдельными запросами ничего не приходит. Может есть вариант как всё это красиво и компактно сделать в одном запросе?

Comment: обычный join двух таблиц поможет. В результате получаете много строк по одну контенту. Дальше у вас два пути, либо на стороне php в цикле разбираете эти много строк и выкладываете так как вам нужно. Либо группируете на стороне mysql (с использованием group by) а значения из files собираете в строку через запятую с помощью group_concat

Comment: @Mike, обычный джойн как раз не подходит по причне того что много строк по одному контенту. А вот про group_concat я не знал. Сейчас буду разбираться, спасибо!

Comment: а много строк это не проблема, делаете order by по контенту и на стороне php в цикле запоминаете какой контент видели в предыдущей строке и пока контент тот же самый накапливаете значения второй таблицы там где это надо. Или вообще собираете это с помщью одной функции PDO https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/504422/194569

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения списка связанных данных одной строкой можно воспользоваться групповой функций GROUP_CONCAT()

```
SELECT `name`, `content`, GROUP_CONCAT(`files`.`adress`)
FROM `content` LEFT JOIN `files` ON `files`.`contentId` = `content`.`id`
GROUP BY `content`.`id`
```